# How significant is your tag score/answered questions ratio?

Tags: discussion, reputation, tags, questions, answers

First off, I apologize if this is a duplicate, I found lots of questions generally related to question/answer ratio, but none directly related to your score within a tag.

Basically, **does the ratio between the number of questions you've answered within a tag to the score you've gained from those answers say something about your expertise within that tag?**

Take the [top users in the jQuery tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/topusers) for example.  The top all-time users in this tag have an answer:score ratio of over 2:1.  This tells me they're pretty good at jQuery (probably an understatement).

However, take my profile for example.  I have about 100 answers and an answer:score ratio that hovers around 1 for the jQuery tag.  What might this indicate?

I suspect that the variety of questions, answers, and different dynamics within each tag muddle the usefulness of this ratio, however It's displayed pretty prominently in the top users area within each tag, which got me thinking.

Comment: I suspect that given how few votes actually occur on a given answer, 1:1 is still pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the tag and the kind of questions you choose to answer, if the tag is not very popular the vote count may stay quite low and if you simply answer questions nobody cares about anyway the same thing will happen, hence your score ratio may end up being quite low.

(*Note that there are tags with a small followship which still generate a lot of votes because the people who engage in the tag's questions may be very dedicated/fanatics*)

Similarily if you are active in a subfield of a tag (not very common i suppose, e.g. [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) questions vs. [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) questions) which is not as popular as the main field your score for the parent tag (C# in the example) might also be lower than that of people who only answer questions "native" to the parent tag.

Overall i would say that the ratio tends to be an indicator of knowledge in the field or rather the ability to effectively communicate knowledge in the field to others but it is not necessarily.